# How to build a dynamic query in java

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a working dynamic query as shown below in MySQL server, Now what I want is to get the results from this query in my Java program. I have searched the internet but couldn't manage to find a relevant solution. Kindly point me in the right direction. Thanks

```
    SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
       CONCAT(
       'COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT case when branch = ''',
       branch,
       ''' then  status  end),''OK'') AS ',
       CONCAT('Branch',branch)
       )
    ) INTO @sql
    FROM Table1;

    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT productName, ', @sql, ' 
    FROM Table1 
    GROUP BY productName');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `PreparedStatement` or it's subtype, the `CallableStatement` in JAVA and call the `execute(<QUERY_NAME>)` from your JAVA code, with proper database connectivity.

```
public void executeProcedure() throws SQLException {
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection");
  CallableStatement cs = this.con.prepareCall("{call <PROCEDURE_NAME>()");
  cs.execute();
}
```

In case you have any parameters to be sent to the procedure, include them as comma separated question marks in the parentheses and then set their values individually.

Refer documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) and tutorials example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html#calling_javadb_mysql).